# Openntpd cannot be uninstalled

Tags: apt, uninstall, ntp

I have openntpd installed when I was trying to install Cloudstack on my Ubuntu 14.10. I no longer needs openntpd but now I cannot uninstall it. I tried `sudo apt-get` `autoremove` and `purge` but I always get following error:

```
deepal@Deepal-ASUS:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove openntpd 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openntpd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 198 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 332328 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openntpd (20080406p-8) ...
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to link /etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service to /dev/null: File exists
dpkg: error processing package openntpd (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openntpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I cannot uninstall a couple of other packages as well because openntpd seems to be a dependency but it cannot be uninstalled. Can anybody help me to solve this annoying problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move this file so the post-removal script will be happy.

`mv /etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service /tmp/`

Comment: Wow!! Worked as a charm!!!!!! Thank you very much